# Join two tables in different databases where the content of table utf_8 text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite

How could I join tow tables in different database files using Python, were the stored data a unicode text in utf_8 (arabic text)?

I have `table1` in `db_b` & `table2` in `db_a`.

I want to join them under column condition in `table1` and store the generated table in third database `"db3"`?

```
b_cursor.execute('SELECT root FROM table1 ' )
output = b_cursor.fetchall()
a_cursor = db_a.cursor()
rows=a_cursor.execute('select root ,word FROM table2 WHERE root IN ("output")').fetchall()
for r in rows:
    i+=1
    print r[0],r[1]
    c_cursor.execute('insert into new_table (no,string,root) values(?,?, ?)',(i, r[1],r[0]))
```

Comment: [Attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the databases, then do a normal join.

Comment: What database are you using? From the syntax I assume MySQL.
Are the databases in the same server?

Comment: @KárolyNagy: check the tags. SQLite.

Comment: The database is sqlite3 embedded in python